# Azure Logic Apps workflow deployment using powershell or ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

Right now in azure logic apps the third party connectors like twitter ,facebook ,salesforce etc requires multifactor authentication which can be done using workflow designer .We are looking forward do the  same using PowerShell ARM Template for different environments. So please suggest the way forward ?

Comment: Did you checkout this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the blog from Jeff Hollan for creating "connections" in logic app using ARM

http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/logicapps/archive/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh.aspx

Comment: One more link using powershell https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicapps/2016/03/18/using-powershell-to-manage-api-connections/

Comment: This link is not working for me: http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/logicapps/archive/2016/02/23/deploying-in-the-logic-apps-preview-refresh.aspx